# How to run svy: regress in R or get R-squared in R for complex survey data

Tags: r, regression, stata, survey

I am trying to get r-squared, or explained variation, in a complex survey data using a linear regression (OLS).

In Stata, this can be done by using svy: regress. In R, however, when I use 'survey' package, there is no option for OLS linear regression. There is svyglm, which is generalized linear model (GLM), but this does not provide a value for explained variation (r-squared) because it isn't OLS. Is there a way to get r-squared for complex survey data in R?

```r
library(survey)

design <- svydesign(id = ~psu, strata = ~strata, weight = ~w_mec, nest = TRUE, data = sample) 

model1 <- svyglm(design = design, bmi ~ 1 + age + black + hispanics + others + female + edu2 + edu3 + edu4 + near_poor + middle + high, family = gaussian(link = "identity"), data = sample)

summary(model1)
```

Above is an example of what I did in R. This doesn't give r-squared because it's GLM. You don't really need to reproduce anything; this isn't a code issue, I just want to know if there is a way to get r-squared for complex survey data in R.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a Gaussian glm (where the population parameter is the OLS parameter) you can just divide the dispersion parameter by the population variance and subtract from 1

Using one of the examples from the `svyglm` help page:

```
> data(api)
> dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)
> api.reg <- svyglm(api.stu~enroll, design=dstrat)
> summary(api.reg)

Call:
svyglm(formula = api.stu ~ enroll, design = dstrat)

Survey design:
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 13.34383   11.46399   1.164    0.246    
enroll       0.81454    0.02459  33.120   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 7331.633)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> nullmodel<-svyglm(api.stu~1,design=dstrat)
> summary(nullmodel)

Call:
svyglm(formula = api.stu ~ 1, design = dstrat)

Survey design:
dstrat<-svydesign(id=~1,strata=~stype, weights=~pw, data=apistrat, fpc=~fpc)

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   498.23      16.06   31.02   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for gaussian family taken to be 137086.3)

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 2

> 1-7331.633/137086.3
[1] 0.9465181
```

You could also get the null-model variance using `svyvar`

```
> svyvar(~api.stu,design=dstrat)
        variance    SE
api.stu   137086 19197
```

And in this case we have the whole population, so we can run `lm` on the population and compare the survey estimate of rsquared with the population value

```
> summary(lm(api.stu ~ enroll,data=apipop))

Call:
lm(formula = api.stu ~ enroll, data = apipop)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-1021.20   -13.76     6.13    29.56   498.98 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 13.613245   1.953709   6.968 3.55e-12 ***
enroll       0.813556   0.002522 322.581  < 2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 92.16 on 6155 degrees of freedom
  (37 observations deleted due to missingness)
Multiple R-squared:  0.9442,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9441 
F-statistic: 1.041e+05 on 1 and 6155 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

As an added bonus answer: if you want the Nagelkerke or Cox-Snell r-squared for binary or count data, there's a function `psrsq`

Comment: this is great, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can get the amount of explained variation just by looking at the residual variance of your model and the residual variance of a null model (model with the explanatory covariates removed, including just an intercept). So the formula you need is:

R2_var = 1 - residual_variance / residual_variance_of_a_null_model

Comment: is the residual variance equivalent to residual deviance in this case?

Comment: @slee no. For residual deviance, similar method exists though: it's called ANODEV. See Grosbois et. al 2008: https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/j.1469-185X.2008.00047.x

Comment: @slee well, I am not sure if it is the case with glm's too

Comment: my confusion comes from the fact that this is GLM, not OLS. You suggested calculating r-squared from residual variance. Then how should I get residual variance in GLM? Is it just like in OLS, which is the variance of (predicted value - observed value)?

Comment: It's not a glm, it's (design-weighted) OLS --- or, more precisely, it is a glm, but it's the special case of a glm that's an OLS linear model.

Comment: In practice this can be computed via `R2 = 1 - deviance(model)/model$null.deviance`.

Answer (score 0):

To get the multiple R2 of a svyglm model, you could also use the *summ* function in the jtools package.

Answer (score -1):

Because "svyglm" objects are also "lm" objects by default -- see `class(model1)` in your example -- you can just run `summary.lm(model1)` to get the R^2.

Comment: `summary.lm` comes from stats, whereas `summary` in the accepted answer is a method in the survey package (see `?survey:::summary.svyglm`)  not sure if using `summary.lm` might not provide all the adjustments necessary for a complex sample dataset?