# Different ways to calculate Rsquared after Regression with complex survey data in R

Tags: r, regression, survey, r-squared

I'm struggling to find out the differences or the "right way" to calculate R² after regression with complex survey data in R. My data includes missings and though I know this is not really state of the art, I chose a complete cases only approach. The data is also clustered. In a very related question [How to run svy: regress in R or get R-squared for complex survey data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424092/how-to-run-svy-regress-in-r-or-get-r-squared-in-r-for-complex-survey-data), I found out about two ways to calculate R². One proposed by [Thomas Lumley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13523536/thomas-lumley) author of the `survey` package (Version 1) and another one proposed by [Innate Imunity is the way](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/5509/innate-imunity-is-the-way) (Version 2). I also found a third one using the `long approach` calculating mean sum of squares and residual sum of squares by inspecting the `summ` function from `jtools` (Version 3).

While Version 2 and 3 yield the same result Version 1 is a little bit different as you can see in the following example. Maybe these are different Pseudo-R²? Help and/or clarification would be very much appreciated. Thank you very much!

*packages, data and regression*

```
library(survey)

airqual <- data.frame(airquality)

airqual_cplx <- svydesign(ids=~Month, data = airqual, weights = ~Wind)


svy_reg <- svyglm(Temp ~ Solar.R + Ozone, airqual_cplx)
sum_reg <- summary(svy_reg)
```

*Version 1: Thomas Lumley*

R²=0.4903556

```
temp_var <- svyvar(~Temp, design=svy_reg$survey.design)[[1]]
disp_reg <- sum_reg$dispersion[[1]]
Rsq1 <- 1-disp_reg/temp_var
print(Rsq1)
```

*Version 2: Innate Imunity is the way*

R²=0.489439

```
deviance.null <- svy_reg$null.deviance
deviance.model <- svy_reg$deviance
Rsq2 <- 1-deviance.model/deviance.null
print(Rsq2)
```

*Version 3: summ in jtools*

R²=0.489439

```
r <- svy_reg$residuals
f <- svy_reg$fitted.values
w <- svy_reg$weights
m <- sum(w * f/sum(w))
mss <-  sum(w * (f - m)^2)
rss <- sum(w * r^2)
Rsq3 <- mss/(mss + rss)
print(Rsq3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all estimating the same thing, they just use slightly  different estimators.

The survey package works from the characterisation of $1-R^2$ as the residual variance divided by the marginal variance, with both of these being well-defined population quantities that are then estimated.

The other approach is to work from the characterisation of $1-R^2$ as the residual sum of squares divided by the total sum of squares. Again, these can be defined as population quantities and then estimated.

I have an aesthetic preference for treating the variances (which are independent of sample size and population size) as the basic quantities, but it really doesn't matter. The differences will be in $n$ vs $n-1$ vs $n-p$ scaling somewhere in the formulas