# Null degrees of freedom to calculate adjusted R-square for a svyglm object

Tags: r, regression, survey

I want to calculate adjusted $R^2$ for a `svyglm` model. To account for a complex cluster sampling design, a set of 80 replicate weights is supplied as part of the dataset. Suppose `m1` is my model object and `des` is the survey design object. Then, following [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/424092/how-to-run-svy-regress-in-r-or-get-r-squared-in-r-for-complex-survey-data) I calculate $R^2$ as follows:

```
1 - m1$deviance/m1$null.deviance
```

Now, to calculate adjusted $R^2$, I use the following formula:
$$
1 - (1 - R^2)\frac{\mathrm{df}_0}{\mathrm{df}_1},
$$
where $\mathrm{df}_0$ is the number of degrees of freedom in the null model and $\mathrm{df}_1$ is the number of degrees of freedom in my fitted model. To get the latter, I use simply `m1$df.residual`. To get the former, shall I use `m1$df.null` or `degf(des)`? The function `poliscidata::fit.svyglm` uses the `m1$df.null`, but according to [this note](https://notstatschat.rbind.io/2019/06/08/design-degrees-of-freedom-brief-note/), the design degrees of freedom should be equal to the number of replicate weights less 1 in my case.

Answer (score 4):

The formula for adjusted $R^2$ isn't designed for cluster-sampled data, and doesn't apply.  However, if you do use it you should use `degf(des)` rather than `m1$df.null`, because the former is what `m1$df.residual` is based on.

If you want degrees of freedom to correct for overfitting, as in adjusted $R^2$ you need something like the [design-based AIC](https://academic.oup.com/jssam/article/3/1/1/915356?login=true) or [Andrew Holbrook's version](https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.04877) of Efron's covariance penalty

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Is the design-based AIC already implemented in R? If I use `stats::AIC` on a `svyglm` model, will it return dAIC?

Comment: Yes, look at `?AIC.svyglm` for details